# Missing Template in Rails app on /create POST action when deployed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm experience some very strange behavior with a Rails app on Heroku. Basically, I'm doing a very straightforward post in a controller and it's failing with a missing template exception. For the life of me I can't figure out why this built-in controller action would expect a template (??). The strange thing is this works just fine locally--the exception only occurs on the deployed app. This is all I'm getting back from the Heroku logs.

```
Started POST "/camps" for ............ at 2011-11-17 23:27:47 +0000
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template camps/create, application/create with
{:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
* "/app/app/views"
* "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/kaminari-0.12.4/app/views"
* "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise_invitable-0.5.7/app/views"
* "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.9/app/views"
):
cache: [POST /camps] invalidate, pass
```

Comment: I'm getting a similar perplexing error. It's not causing problems, but it's still confusing. My error is: `No template found for PagesController#contact, rendering head :no_content`

`render nothing: true`, actually doesn't work for me. It puts me on a blank page `/contact`. I only created the `contact` route so that I could send an email.

Comment: Ah, of course. `head :no_content` is what I needed. Still confusing why I would need that for a post request, but I guess it's because it's a non-restful route/action.

Answer (score 9):

It's not supposed to render anything?

Do you have `render :nothing => true` in your action?

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't render anything. It's a POST action that's created automatically because I have a "camp" model resourced in the routes file (resources :camps). So, the only time it should be looking for a template is if the action fails to redirect before exiting the method. Anyway, I created a new POST action called "make" and that works, so something about have the default "create" method in there just wasn't making Rails happy.

Comment: Though both solutions will work, I would definitely say that `render :nothing => true` is the preferred solution here. Why make an extra action in your controller if you don't have to?

Comment: Rendering nothing also works for me, but the fundamental question is this. If this is a POST call, by default, shouldn't it return nothing back? Why do we have to specify explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

If it's anything like the issue I just had, the problem is that for some reason rails doesn't know where to go after it gets done processing your post request.  Here's some code of mine that created exactly the same error:

```
def create
  if params[:favorite] == true
    current_user.favorite == true
  else
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

The problem is that if the first part of the if statement was true, I set the a the user favorite property to true.  Then I did nothing.  I forgot to inform rails where to go next.   Rails continued on to the bottom of the create method, and found nowhere to go, so it thought I must have defined a default create template, and went looking for that. When it didn't find one, it basically turned to me and said, "Where the heck am I supposed to go next?

The fixed code is as follows.

```
def create
  if params[:favorite] == true
    current_user.favorite == true
  end
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

In this fixed code, regardless of how the if statement turns out, I still told rails that it is supposed to go to the root route, aka my homepage, after it gets done with this method.