# Rails 3 Controller update action works locally but not on heroku, get missing template error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am experiencing a similar problem as this previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175945/missing-template-in-rails-app-on-create-post-action-when-deployed-to-heroku), but the answer doesn't seem to fit me. So I wanted to follow up with my issue.

I have an action in my controller that updates my Profile model using a checkbox. When I click the checkbox with the app running locally I have no problems. However when I deploy to Heroku I get:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template profiles/show_hometown_settings with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/app/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails_log_stdout/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails3_serve_static_assets/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/paperclip/app/views"):
```

I added both a `_show_hometown_settings.html.erb` file and a `_show_hometown_settings.js.erb` file but neither did the trick. Checking my checkbox gave me vanilla code on my screen and the above error.

If I add `show_hometown_settings.html.erb` I no longer get vanilla code. I see the `show_hometown_settings.html.erb` template, but I still get the error and I don't get redirected to my `settings_path`, which is the whole point (check to update, post to db, redirected to make further settings changes). Can anyone help me out with this?

Here is the controller action:

```
def show_hometown_settings
  @profile = current_user.profile
  if @profile.show_hometown == true
    if @profile.update_attributes(:show_hometown => false)
      redirect_to settings_path
    else
      redirect_to settings_path, :notice => 'Oops, something went wrong. Please try again.'
    end
  elsif @profile.show_hometown == false
    if @profile.update_attributes(:show_hometown => true)
      redirect_to settings_path
    else
    redirect_to settings_path, :notice => 'Oops, something went wrong. Please try again.'
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the form I use for the action:

```
<%= form_tag({:action => "show_hometown_settings", :controller => "profiles"}, :html => {:multipart => true }) do %>
  <%= check_box_tag(:show_hometown, 1, @user.profile.show_hometown ? true : false) %>
  <%= @user.profile.hometown %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE:** Here is the part of my `routes.rb` file that references the action:

```
match "profiles/show_hometown_settings", :to => "profiles#show_hometown_settings"
```

**UPDATE 2:** Following the question below, I got a different error and my logs show a route issue:

This returns

```
`The page you were looking for doesn't exist (404)`
```

And in my `heroku logs --tail` I see

```
2012-01-19T23:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/profiles/show_hometown_settings" for 98.218.231.113 at 2012-01-19 23:13:47 +0000
2012-01-19T23:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-19T23:13:47+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/profiles/show_hometown_settings"):
```

If I change the route from :via => [:put] to :via => [:post] it works. Hopefully that's alright.

Comment: Are you sure you have the relevant files commited in git?

Comment: Almost positive. What boggles my mind is if I commit `show_hometown_settings`, I still get an error.

Comment: Have you tried adding `return` after the redirects? It kinda sounds like Rails is trying to render the show_hometown_settings action, even though every logical path results in a redirect.

Comment: What would that look like? `redirect_to settings_path, return`?

Comment: I just added the relevant match in my `routes.rb` file as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to have that template file at all since you aren't rendering a view, you're only redirecting.

What's probably happening is that your `if-elsif` logic is breaking down and the code is never reaching those redirects (because neither of the `if` blocks are evaluating to `true`).  If Rails doesn't get a `redirect_to` call, then by default it will render the view for the controller action (which is what it is trying to do).

I would change it around to this:

Route:

```
match "profiles/show_hometown_settings", :to => "profiles#show_hometown_settings", :as => :show_hometown_settings, :via => [:put]
```

Controller:

```
def show_hometown_settings
  if current_user.profile.update_attributes(:show_hometown => params[:show_hometown])
    redirect_to settings_path
  else
    redirect_to settings_path, :notice => 'Oops, something went wrong. Please try again.'
  end
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_tag(show_hometown_settings_path, :method => :put) do %>
  <%= check_box_tag(:show_hometown, 1, @user.profile.show_hometown ? true : false) %>
  <%= @user.profile.hometown %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I've updated my question with what I get as a result of this. I feel like I'm getting closer...

Comment: If I change the route `:via` from `put` to `post` it works! I'll have to look back over my `if-else` logic to see what I didn't do properly. Thank you!

Comment: @tvalent2 `POST` is used for creating records in the database.  Since you are updating them, you should be using `PUT`.  Please add `:method => :put` to the `form_tag` like shown in my updated answer above and it should fix that issue for you.  You're welcome! :)

Comment: Yeah I thought I should use POST. I'll give that a go and try it out. You're a life saver.

Comment: Glad to help!  Best of luck to you